# Header location issue

Tags: php, html

So, I have a signup form. In it, are the fields (like first name, last name, email, password, retype password, etc.), and the signup button. So, from the signup page, the user can actually just change the url from login.php to home.php and access the homepage the wrong way. So, for that, I used a small PHP logic to prevent that. Here's that PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
  header("location:home.php");
} else {
  header("location:login.php");
}
```

So, I kept this PHP code on the home.php page, because, that's the page the user is accessing wrongly. So, 'sub', is just the name for the signup button. Here's the HTML code for that button:

```
<input type="button" type="submit" value="Create An Account" name="sub" class="but" id="press" style="margin-top:-1px; font-family:'Rajdhani'; border: none; border-radius:25px; outline: none" onclick="checkEmail()"></input>
```

So, with that PHP code, it's working. Like, I can't change the URL to home.php when on the signup page. If I try to do that, it will just send me back to the signup page, the same page, so I can't access the homepage, unless I submit the signup form correctly. So, here's where the issue arises. If I submit the signup form correctly, and everything is validated correctly as well, when I click on the signup button, it should redirect to the homepage, because I accessed it correctly, which it did previously, without this PHP code. But now, with this PHP code, when I fill in all the fields for the signup form correctly, and click the signup button, it just sends me back to the same page (signup.php), and doesn't send me to the homepage (home.php). Here is the action to my form (where all the fields and submit button is):

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0)" id="mainForm">
```

It is javascript:void(0), because on another file, I have some AJAX running for error messages, so it's not home.php, but I think this is the reason it isn’t working, because the action is not home.php, but if I keep it as home.php, the AJAX won’t work, so I need to keep it as javascript:void(0) for the AJAX to work. So, I need to keep the action as javascript:void(0), but at the same time, ensure that the PHP url thing is working as well.

So, in conclusion, the logic where you can't change the URL is working. If they try to change the URL to home.php, it will just redirect back to the same page, login.php, which is good. Now, previously without that PHP code, when you signup, you would be taken to the homepage (where the data is stored) and the data would be represented using sessions. This would happen, you would get redirected, only if every field was filled and validated correctly. Even now, with this PHP code, it's only occurring when each field is validated, but when correct, it's just redirecting to the same page, not the home page. So, I need to resolve this particular issue.

So, any help? Please. Thank you.

Comment: why not use $_SESSION?

Comment: So, if(isset($_SESSION['sub'])) { on the home.php page, and on the login page, I set the session?

Comment: let me share my code snipped with you. Summarizingly your question, I can understand that you want the user to stay on signup page unless he sign's up and logs in. right?

Comment: Nope isn't working. Tried session, but still even if everything is correct it redirects to the same page.

Comment: @AsadMehmood Absolutely correct, but if the user enters everything correctly and clicks the signup button, they should get redirected to the home page.

Comment: What you are doing here, is nothing but ridiculous at this point. You keep asking the same question, from this or your other account, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69709670/1427878 In comments you said multiple times, that you already _had_ your signup/login system written - and yet here, under the currently existing answer, you once again appear to have no clue how to check if the user is currently successfully logged in, or not.

Comment: This is not how you do logins. You need to store in the Session the fact that the user has successfully logged in. Then that information will be available for all subsequent requests as well until they log out. A POST variable cannot achieve that. Plenty of examples of this online already, no need to invent your own system. Stop making it up, because you keep getting it wrong, you've already had this advice multiple times. Writing an authentication system is _not_ a good task for an inexperienced developer.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no such thing as a closing `</input>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

As of discussion in the comments try this code snippet and check if it works for you.

**Home.php**

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
    header("location:login.php"); //Not logged in redirect to login
    }
```

and on **Login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
header("location:home.php"); //yes logged in redirect to homepage
}
```

Hope this helps. Queries are welcomed.

Thanks

**Update**
I forgot to add. On successful signup/login set the session. For instance:

```
$_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['user_id'];
```

**Update 02**
**Login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
header("location:home.php"); //yes logged in redirect to homepage
}
    
if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
 // username and password sent from form 
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'rootpassword');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
             
              
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
              
$sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$active = $row['user_id'];
              
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
              
 // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
                
if($count == 1) {
$_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['user_id'];
                 
header("location: home.php");
}else {
$error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
}
```

Comment: What is user_session?

Comment: And what is $row['user_id']? and where do we keep it. I don't get what u mean by successful signup/login. Also in the first snippet, the if and else both are header("location:login.php");

Comment: user_session is the key. $_SESSION is like an object 
{
 "key":"value","key","value"
}

here user_session is a key varaible. you can set it to anything you like. it can be user_id, user_email, User_name etc

Comment: Ok I know that, but what would it be. Like the signup button or what?

Comment: Ok, I'll set it to email. And what is $row['user_id'] and where do we keep it?

Comment: $row['user_id'] is the variable. when you login. you apply the query to select * from users where user=$user and pass=$pass. when this query is implemented it responds an object of user which contains user details that may contain user_id user_name etc. then you fetch_assoc and loop throught a $row. so this is that $row array and extracting user_id. Further assigning the ID to session varaible so session is not left empty and you are properly redirected to homepage.

Comment: If you donot set session then you wont be able to redirect to homepage. as we have implemented a check, If session is empty redirect to login

Comment: Ok, can you just the keep the code which is required to just prevent user changing url unless they signup correctly. Just that code. Not any $row['user_id'] or anything.

Comment: Never mind. It's working. Like I can't change the url to home.php. But if everything is correct, it's not redirecting to the homepage. It's still just taking me back to the same page.

Comment: if you remove $row your session wont work and you wont be redirected to homepage. that plays an important role in taking you to homepage.

Comment: Ok which page should I keep that $row in? Home.php or login.php? And can it be something like this?:

$_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

Comment: Let me edit my answer for you

Comment: Ok, thank you. I can't see the edit though.

Comment: Please have a look at update 02

Comment: Hey this is an entire login system. I'm just looking for something which prevents the user from changing url to home.php, but if signup fields are filled and validated correctly, then only we redirect them to home.php page.

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
header("location:home.php"); //yes logged in redirect to homepage
}` 

This part of code is the trick. This will prevent user to move to any other page unless he is authorized!

Comment: Yes. It is not letting user change url to anything else when on the login page unless they are authorised. But even after filling out the signup forms correctly and clicking the signup button, it's not redirecting to the home page. It's still just taking me back to the same page.

Comment: ` if (!isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
    header("location:login.php"); //Not logged in redirect to login
    }` place this code on your home.php page.

Comment: `if($count == 1) {
$_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['user_id'];
                 
header("location: home.php");
}else {
$error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}` and check this part of code, as this redirects the user to homepage after successful login

Comment: Where should that $count stuff be, and what is $count? It seems to be undefined.

Comment: And I tried that $count code. Doesn't help. It's still just taking me back to the same page. Not the homepage.

Comment: Asad, the $count code isn't helping, it's still just taking me back to same page. Not the homepage.

Comment: And $count seems to be undefined.